# StackOverflowError when retriving ManyToMany join table with Java EJB 3

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have the following entity mapings for my EJB3 application that map a many-to-many relationship:

```
@Entity
Crawl{
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pk.crawl")
    public List<Change> changes;
}

@Entity
Change{
    @EmbeddedId
    ChangePK pk;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    Date changeDate;
}

@Embeddable
ChangePK{
    @ManyToOne
    Crawl crawl;

    @ManyToOne
    Page page;
}

@Entity
Page{
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.page")
    List<Change> changes;
}
```

I am trying to get all of the changes that are related to a crawl and order them by date using:

```
this.entityManager
    .createQuery("SELECT c FROM Change c WHERE 
                  c.pk.crawl.id = :id 
                  ORDER BY c.changeDate DESC")
   .setParameter("id", crawl.getId());
```

This is giving me a stack overflow error. I belive the eager fetch may have something to do with it but in every other occurence I want the changes loaded with a crawl and it will cause a lot of problems in the rest of my application if I change the fetch type to lazy.

I have overriden `hashCode` and `equals` methods for each class.

### Edit:

`hashcode` and `equals` code:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + id;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Crawl other = (Crawl) obj;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

These are generated by Eclipse and I have selected the primary keys to use in them, the other classes all use the same thing.

Comment: I would recommend jpa or hibernate tags instead of some of the others (e.g., stackoverflowerror or ejb).

Comment: @bkail could you explain why? I've been using EJB3 annotations (JPA) without any problem for 4 years.

Comment: @Augusto I mean stackoverflow.com question tags; JPA or hibernate experts might miss the question with the current set of tags.

Comment: OK thanks, I have changed them.

Answer (score 0):

If the whole tree of object tree is big, there's *no way** to avoid the stackoverflow as hibernate resolves the dependencies recursively, which is ok for 99.9% of the cases (in 8 years of using hibernate, this is the first time that I've seen this error).

One alternative to fix this, is to increase the stack size, but that will increase the size on all the application threads (which might not be something good). so for example you can add the option `-Xss1m` when you run the JVM and you'll get a 1mb stack size. (the default stack size varies from platform to platform, but I think it's usually 512k)

Another alternative is to change the mapping, but I think all include denormalising the table a bit.
One option is to flatten the tree, so given a specific Crawl, you can retrieve all the children of the crawl with one query. In this case, the collection Crawl.changes contains all the children, grandsons, etc of the crawl.

**there is always a way*

Comment: Thanks for the response, I dont think that it is an issue with database size, currently I am testing it with 1 crawl and 6 pages and 6 changes.

What exactly do you mean by faltening the tree? Would that involve the combination of the change and page table?

Comment: Ups, that's different. Can you validate that you don't have a circular relationship? For example PageX includes ChangeX; ChangeX has CrawlX and CrawlX includes ChangeX.

Comment: I believe that is the case. As it stands there is only one crawl so all of the changes would be storing that crawl, and the crawl would be storing all of the changes. I though hibernate would detect the circular relationship and not get stuck in the loop. Is there a way to work around this? Am I mapping a many to many relationship wrong? Am I missing some annotations perhaps?

Comment: I don't think it does for one to many relationships, but it does it for many-to-many relationships. It's not ideal, if you extract the relationship to another table, you could *trick* hibernate and map the relationship as a many-to-many. Oh, and can you post the hashcode and equals? Because this might happen if they are not correct.

Comment: I have edited the original post with the hashcode and equals methods. What exactly would extracting the relationships involve?